# Android Studio unable to resolve ?android: resources

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-lint

Android Studio is complaining about being unable to resolve ?android resources in xml layouts.

It is building and running these projects without complain, but whenever I look at my layout or do a commit it is highlighting them as errors.

[image: Screenshot of Error message]

Any suggestions for solving this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a sort-of solution: If I go into my build.gradle and set my compileSdkVersion to be something other than 19 the error messages go away.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'
...
```

Obviously this isn't a very good solution, I'm going to try removing SDK 19 and re-adding it to see if it will resolve the issue for that SDK.

Comment: Yep, that did it.I wish I had thought of that a few weeks ago, that was really irritating.
(I didn't twig that it was a system-wide thing until I started a new project and had the same problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this attribute

`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`

Comment: Again, this works fine but is highlighted as an error.

Comment: @android:color/white is highlighted as an error the same way.